# Sum value's in query and display this in table filtered by project ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on a website for school but I ran into a problem. I have to sum values which are in a different table then what is being displayed on the front page.

Let me explain further:

[Front page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpoHw.png)

In this screenshot, you see the headers which contains: Plan and Do

- **Plan** = The amount of time you plan on spending on the project in total.
- **Do** = The amount of time you have spend on the total project.

This is the simple query and code I use to populate the table:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `projecten`"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {?>
    <tr class="active">
        <td style="display:none;" class="id"><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Naam'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Plan'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Do'];?></td>
        <td>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-success" href="ExpandedProject.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">Expand</a>
                <a class="btn btn-default btn-danger" href="Delete_Project.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'];?>">Verwijderen</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php  } ?>
```

Now what i tried doing:

```
SQL = SELECT *, sum(tasks.Plan) FROM `projecten`,`tasks`
```

This worked but because I have 1 table for all the tasks for different projects this will be adding tasks which are not part of the project. So i deleted this again.

I also tried using the above query and then adding a where which filtered the project id's in the tasks table.

My question is how do I make it so it will sum Plan and Do and display these values properly and being filtered by the project ID

Just wanted to let you know that I have 2 left hands when it comes to PHP so I'm sorry if there are some mistakes in the code :)

I also wanted to put in more pictures of the tables I have but I couldn't add them because of my reputation.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `sum()` is a good start, `group by` is the next step.

Comment: Looking up the SQL  `JOIN` syntax should probably be your first step

Comment: Robert; When tackling sql problems, I think you will find it easier to separate your SQL problem from the PHP code (and easier to get help). Show us your source table form (schema) with example data, give an example (in a table form) of what you want to see as a result, and I promise someone will get you an answer with amazing speed.

Comment: @SteveJ Unfortunatly i cannot add more than 1 image to my question because of my rep. I now have the SQL like this: SELECT *, sum(tasks.Plan) FROM `projecten`, `tasks` WHERE tasks.ProjectID = 1. For some reason this doubles the outcome. Also when i load my page i do not have a project ID so i cant make it dynamic. How do i fetch the project id's before i inject the data into the columns?

Comment: `SELECT p.id, p.naam, sum(t.plan) plan, sum(t.do) do FROM projecten p LEFT JOIN tasks t ON p.id = t.projectid GROUP BY p.id, p.naam`

Comment: @trincot This worked perfectly! thank you! if you would like could you make this comment an awnser explaining what you did. So i can understand it and then i can also set it as an awnser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT    p.id, 
          p.naam, 
          coalesce(sum(t.plan),0) plan, 
          coalesce(sum(t.do),0) do 
FROM      projecten p 
LEFT JOIN tasks t 
       ON p.id = t.projectid 
GROUP BY  p.id, 
          p.naam
```

The `LEFT JOIN` is an outer join that will link records from the two tables, with the additional feature that if no corresponding *tasks* record is found for  given *projecten* record, the *projecten* record will still be in the result, but with `null` values for what normally would be columns from the tasks record.

The `group by` clause will aggregate multiple tasks records, so that you still get only one record per *projecten* record. The `sum` expressions tell the SQL engine how to make this aggregation.

The `coalesce` function is included to make sure that a *projecten* record without any *tasks* record, will not show `null` for *Plan* and *Do*, but 0 instead. If you prefer the blanks in that case, then remove `coalesce(..., 0)`, leaving just the `sum(...)`.